# Proof of separability of $Lp[0,1]$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

So I have to show the separability of $Lp[0,1]$. My idea was to use step functions with rational values which should be dense in the set of all step functions. But I´m not sure if my idea was the right one and I don´t know how to formulate the proof mathematically then.

Comment: Use the density of continuous functions in $L_p[0,1]$. Then approximate any continuous function by a polynomial with rational coefficients.